# Feature request: Personal 'favorite questions' list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

Sometimes I see a question that I'd like to know the answer to, but that has not been answered yet.

It would be nice if I could save that question in a personal 'favorite questions' list, so that I could easily find it again later (to check back with the question later if it has been answered).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That little star under the up/down vote buttons next to each question is used for saving favorite questions.

Then, to review your favorites, you can go to your profile (click your name), and you'll see a "Favorites" tab.

[star http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8026/screenshot2zo.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8026/screenshot2zo.png)

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I hadn't discovered that yet.

Comment: What OS/Browser are you using? That font is cute.

Comment: For what it's worth, the preferred method of highlighting parts of images on Meta is to use freehand circles, and some pickier users demand a drop-shadow effect.

Comment: @voyager: Ubuntu 9.04/Firefox 3.0.

@Chris: Noted. (And with 7 upvotes on your comment, it must be *really* preferred!)

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu 9.04/FF 3.0 ... You don't have neither the `liberation-fonts` nor the `ms-ttf` font packages right? That must be it :)

Comment: @voyager: no results for `locate` on either of those fonts.  So, I have no idea which font my version of Firefox is using.

Comment: @Mark: you can use firebug to check that, but most likely is ´free sans´ or ´deja vu sans´